# Finding Value of given limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please help me with this question.

Find the value of
$$\lim_{t\to0}\left[1^{\frac1{\sin^2(t)}}+2^{\frac1{\sin^2(t)}}+\cdots+n^{\frac1{\sin^2(t)}}\right]^{\sin^2(t)}$$
$\begin{align}&(1)\, n^2\\&(2)\, \infty\\&(3)\, n\\&(4)\,\text{Limit can't be determined}
\end{align}$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=\sin^2 t$. By factoring, observe your limit is

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}n\left((1/n)^{1/x}+(2/n)^{1/x}+...+1\right)^x.$$

From here, you should be able to evaluate the limit (hint: what happens to $a^b$ as $b\to \infty$ for $|a|<1$).

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the variable
$$
z = \frac{1}{\sin^2 t}\;,
$$
write the limit as
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \left(1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z  \right)^{1/z}\;.
$$
From the power rule $\ln a^b = b\,\ln a\,$, we deduce:
$$
\ln \left(1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z  \right)^{1/z} = \frac{\ln(1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z)}{z}\;.
$$
To determine the behaviour of this expression for $z\rightarrow\infty\,$, we employ the l'Hospital rule:
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \ln \left(1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z  \right)^{1/z} 
=
\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln(1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z)}{z} 
$$
$$
=
\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{1^z \ln 1 + 2^z \ln 2 + ... + n^z \ln n}{1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z} = \ln n\;.
$$

Consequently,
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \left(1^z + 2^z + ... + n^z  \right)^{1/z} = n\;.
$$

Comment: in third line, shouldnt there be ln  on RHS

Comment: @Olivia Yes, I missed it. Thank you! Will fix.